# rxjs subject switchmap http error

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, ionic2

I'm using `Subject`, `switchMap` and `.next()` to cancel previous pending http calls when a new `http.get()` request is fired.

The problem is when i handle a http error (like timeout) the method `_postMPCHC.next(...)` called in html do not work anymore...
Do i need to recreate the subscription on error ? How ?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, Toast} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {AppSettings} from '../../appSettings';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/video/video.html'
})
export class VideoPage {
  _postMPCHC: any= new Subject();

  constructor(private http: Http, private nav: NavController) {
    this.defineHttp();
  }

  defineHttp() {

    var sub = this._postMPCHC.switchMap((x: string) => {
      let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('token', AppSettings.API_TOKEN);
      params.set('prog', 'mhz');
      params.set('prog', 'mpchc');
      params.set('action', x);

      return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT, { search: params })

    }).timeout(5000, new Error('timeout exceeded')).subscribe(x => { },
      error => {
        let toast = Toast.create({
          message: 'Server response: ' + <any>error,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'middle'
        });
        this.nav.present(toast);
      })

  }
}
```

Comment: can u resubscribe on error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when stream gets an error - it ends. If you want to handle the http error but keep main stream alive, you should handle error on the level of http stream.
See this article - [Error handling. What to do when error kills stream](https://github.com/sychd/wooden-dummy/blob/master/rxjs/error-handling.tip.md).

So, in your case you can handle error at `return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT, { search: params })` line by adding `.pipe(catchError(...))` - it will keep your mai stream alive and will catch http errors